# SQL UNION: Is the order of duplicate elimination defined?

Tags: sql

Although the question seems to be somehow obvious, I could not find a clear specification for how duplicate elimination of UNION DISTINCT is defined (I hope it's defined in general and not per database system):

When writing

```
select * from table A 
    union distinct
select * from table B
```

and A and B have duplicate values (with regard to the key fields), can I rely on a precedence of the records from A over the records of B ?

For example, lets assume A has one record with the key field with value 1 and a data field with value 'x' and B also has one record, also with key value 1, but with data field value 'y'.
Can I be sure, that the result will have the value 'x' in the data field?

Comment: You'd have two rows ... 1, x and 1, y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to detect the order of elimination, because all columns, not only the key ones, are taken into consideration when performing a `UNION`:

```
create table a(k int primary key,x int);
create table b(k int primary key,y int);
insert into a(k,x) values (1,1),(2,2);
insert into b(k,y) values (1,3),(2,2);

select * from a
union distinct
select * from b
```

The above produces three rows, not two ([demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/56f2a/1)):

```
1 1
2 2
1 3
```

Even though the primary key of `1` is present in both tables, the non-key column in these tables have different values. This preserves both rows - `{1, 1}` and `{1, 3}` in the result of the `UNION`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `Distinct` removes rows that are entirely identical. You will have both (1, x) and (1, y) in your result.

Answer (score 1):

UNION [DISTINCT] removes duplicate result rows. So if you select columns (1,x) and (1,y) from your tables, no matter how often they occur and in which of the tables, you will get both rows, and each row just once.

The result is the same as

```
select distinct *
from (select * from a union all select * from b);
```

just shorter and probably faster.

BTW: The keyword DISTINCT after UNION is not allowed in all dbms. Usually you would just write UNION. On the other hand some dbms require an alias for any derived table as in `from (select * from a union all select * from b) dummy;` for above query.